# SparkSQL Windows: Creating Frame Based On Array Column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am looking to use SparkSQL's window function, but with a custom condition on the frame specification.

The dataframe being operated on is as follows:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|              userid|           elementid|       prerequisites|score|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|a                   |1                   |[]                  |  1  |
|a                   |2                   |[]                  |  1  |
|a                   |3                   |[]                  |  1  |
|b                   |1                   |[]                  |  1  |
|a                   |4                   |[1, 2]              |  1  |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

Every element in the `prerequisites` column is a value in another row's `elementid` column.

I would like to create a window where I partition by `userid`, and then grab all preceding rows where `elementid` is contained in the present row's `prerequisites` column.

Once I attain this window, I want to perform a `sum` on the `score` column.

Desired output for the above example:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|              userid|           elementid|       prerequisites|sum  |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
|a                   |1                   |[]                  |  0  |
|a                   |2                   |[]                  |  0  |
|a                   |3                   |[]                  |  0  |
|b                   |1                   |[]                  |  0  |
|a                   |4                   |[1, 2]              |  2  |
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

Notice how because user `a` is the only user with the prerequisites of its element preceding it, its the only one with > 0 `sum`.

The closest question I saw was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895445/spark-window-function-with-condition-on-current-row) question, which utilises collect_list.

However, that doesn't construct a window so much as collect a potential list of IDs. Anyone have any ideas on how to construct the aforementioned window?

Comment: can you  give your sample data completely and expected output ?

Comment: Added! Thanks Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window,UserDefinedFunction}

scala> df.show()
+------+---------+-------------+-----+
|userid|elementid|prerequisites|score|
+------+---------+-------------+-----+
|     a|        1|           []|    1|
|     a|        2|           []|    1|
|     a|        3|           []|    1|
|     b|        1|           []|    1|
|     a|        4|       [1, 2]|    1|
+------+---------+-------------+-----+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- userid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- elementid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prerequisites: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- score: string (nullable = true)

scala> val W = Window.partitionBy("userid")

scala> val df1 = df.withColumn("elementidList", collect_set(col("elementid")).over(W))
                   .withColumn("elementidScoreMap", map_from_arrays(col("elementidList"), collect_list(col("score").cast("long")).over(W)))
                   .withColumn("common", array_intersect(col("prerequisites"), col("elementidList")))
                   .drop("elementidList", "score") 

scala> def getSumUDF:UserDefinedFunction = udf((Score:Map[String,Long], Id:String) => {
     | var out:Long =  0
     | Id.split(",").foreach{ x => out = Score(x.toString) + out}
     | out})

scala> df1.withColumn("sum", when(size(col("common")) =!= 0  ,getSumUDF(col("elementidScoreMap"), concat_ws(",",col("prerequisites")))).otherwise(lit(0)))
          .drop("elementidScoreMap", "common")
          .show()
+------+---------+-------------+---+
|userid|elementid|prerequisites|sum|
+------+---------+-------------+---+
|     b|        1|           []|  0|
|     a|        1|           []|  0|
|     a|        2|           []|  0|
|     a|        3|           []|  0|
|     a|        4|       [1, 2]|  2|
+------+---------+-------------+---+
```